# Thought experiment - Summer Camp for All rather than Universal Basic Income

Tags: economy

Here's a thought - municipalities and non-profits would build lots of housing and food courts for those in need, and in exchange people would work to build and maintain the housing and food courts and do any work needed such as teaching and health care and construction of improved streets for biking and transit. People would be free to do the work they want, the work they enjoy and gives them satisfaction. There would be many work opportunities such as day care, elder care, operating the transit system etc. Cars would be available in a pool for work-related needs but people would live in bike-able walk-able transit friendly density and not need a car for their daily needs.

There would be very little cost to this scheme, as most costs are due to labor, but that would now be free and provided by the residents. I am calling it Summer Camp because that is a place where everyone is busy and happy and active and contributes - there is social pressure to get up and get out and do something fun and productive and not just lay about in your bed all day. Also, in summer camp, it is owned collectively and everyone is proud of their camp and people won't litter or make a mess - they feel affection and ownership of their summer camp. People also are closer to nature and doing environmentally destructive acts that benefit only a few such as building a big house in the wetland would be seen as greedy and negative and counter to the collective use and environmental purpose the wetland.

This summer camp system would benefit students, researchers, writers, artists, musicians, performers, scientists, therapists and those who want to focus on doing public-focused service without the stress of housing or food.

Our current economic system is based upon payments and possibly saving for the future for your retirement - in summer camp we collectively acknowledge we will take care of each other at every stage of life - people would do work that interests them such as day care, being a teacher, caring for the sick and elderly and those in need. Everyone gets what they need without worry.

Questions / doubts: How would the paying economy be affected by so many people migrating to the free summer camp system? If you people lived with dignity in nice housing and had good food by doing any supply chain work needed, then who would work for profit-focused businesses? Who would work in the rich man's restaurant and mow his lawn and clean his house? The suburban life in America is based upon a large pool of people to do low paid dead-end service work. Who would do undesirable work such as fracking when we would have lots of people working to build solar and wind electricity facilities and storage and transmission systems - if we focus on doing all the good work needed, and we no longer have the threat of financial ruin from losing a job - who would do undesirable jobs - or even would people still be focused on doing a good job and being on time? Would all the free food and housing and optional choose-your-own-job let people off the hook and they would become lazy and not work much? Would people still serve each other in restaurants or would it be more of a family-style buffet?

Endless possibilities and questions!

Thoughts?

Comment: Congratulations, you just reinvented Communism. I’m pretty sure that at least one of the Communist countries tried this thing IRL, too, though I’m not an historian so I can’t say for sure.

Comment: This question is not about Worldbuilding, as defined by our [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Please [edit] the question to make it more appropriate for this site, and take our [tour] to learn more about how Worldbuilding.SE works.

Comment: Technically this would be more [Utopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia#Economics) or maybe [commune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commune) for a working model that is close @nick012000

Comment: I am also voting to close as this is too broad - I would suggest you edit it and focus more on "We have this summer program" then pick your biggest question and ask that based on your socioeconomic setup (with criteria for what makes a good answer). I would also suggest using our [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) for this as it can be a process

Comment: Karl Marx envisaged two stages of post-capitalist economy, and therefore society, in accordance with his view of dialectical and historical materialism: stage one, socialism, summarized as *"from each according to his capacities, to each according to his work"*; and stage two, communism, summarized as *"from each according to his ability, to each according to his needs"*. Needless to say, all attempts to actually create a socialist (or, in the case of the Soviet Union, even a communist) society on this true world have failed rather abysmally.

Answer (score 7):

**Labour != Skills**

The single biggest issue I see with this proposal is that it assumes that your economy is based on goods only and that services are all interchangeably bundled up in this box called 'Labour'. Services as a rule are as much, if not more, a part of the economy as goods are and that's because you can't just interchange different people to do all manner of different jobs if your labour force hasn't been trained in all the skills they could possibly need, and no-one is going to do that because training costs a lot of money and training everyone to be a generalist who is just at home building a house as cutting hair as managing logistics and purchasing for a restaurant is massively inefficient.

This is a problem that has been understood for a long time and is one that Communism in its many forms over the last century has grappled with unsuccessfully. After all, how do you convince a person who has been trained in a skill that's far more valuable than the average person in the community that his or her contribution is exactly equal to everyone else's? What happens when that person wants a bigger say in how things are run given his or her greater contribution? If you concede this greater say, how do you convince the unskilled workers that they still have equality?

Ultimately, your summer camp is doomed to fail, not because it's a bad idea in theory, but because in practice the people who learn trades and more valuable skills won't be content to apply their skills for subsistence only (think room and board), they'll want to take those skills and make more money with them to better their life. That means you're either going to have a constant under-supply of skills, and your training costs will go through the roof to build up skills that are ultimately going to want to leave as soon as they can. As a result, you're building a future ghetto, albeit with the very best of intentions.

Ultimately, as an aside, this is also why many communistic nations during the cold war period had such nationalistic outlooks; doing your bit for the country was intended to be motivation for those who were contributing more to stick with the program, and encouraging those who tended towards laziness to work for something bigger than themselves, especially as their needs would be met either way. In a communist system, motivation will always be your key problem as if your basic needs are met regardless, many tend to do as little as possible, and those contributing above the average instead want more to balance out their own contribution. Putting everyone's contribution in the context of the nation was designed to counteract personal interests, although whether it was a success at the time is matter more for historians than myself.

Comment: In response to your last paragraph, the fact that the large majority of formerly communist nations are no longer communist would probably indicate that it was not a success, or at least not as much of one as a capitalist system.

Comment: @Gryphon I do generally agree with your comment but I also feel compelled to concede that national economies and regimes are complicated beasts and that I therefore have to allow for the fact that there could be other elements that resulted in these collapses other than the social engineering aspects. I suspect AlexP would be able to give a more definitive answer than I can on this last point.